# Getting a Row Count and keeping the columns with no rows are returned

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If I run something like this:

```
select [agent_name], [agent_department], count(*) as [row_count]
from [table_name]
where [agent_name] IS NOT NULL
group by [agent_name] [agent_department];
```

Nothing will come back if there are no records to return (i.e. the table is empty).

If I run this

```
select count(*) as [row_count]
from [table_name]
where [agent_name] IS NOT NULL
```

I will get a row_count of 0.

Is there a way I can run the first query, and, if there are no records, have it return row_count 0?

Comment: If the table is empty, what do you expect to get back for `[agent_name]` and `[agent_department]`?

Comment: That behaviour is by design. In a query which only returned an aggregated `COUNT` value then 0 is returned, however, if you're first query you have no rows, returned so `[agent_name]`and `[agent_department]` have no value.

Comment: I have a table for running validations. I need the empty row set to be inserted into this table. If there are no rows to return, I am going to insert a row that says "validation passed, nothing to return".

Comment: You could simply do the insert, and use `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0` to do another insert if the first one did nothing. The generic alternatives are more complicated (`IF NOT EXISTS ...`, `UNION ALL NULL, NULL, 0` with `MAX` and `GROUP BY`).

Comment: I've never used @@rowcount before, can you post an example as the answer instead of as a comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be very beautiful, but it should bring back what you want:

I start with a tiny mockup:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(agent_name varchar(100),agent_department varchar(100));
```

--The query will read your `SELECT` within a `CTE`.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    select [agent_name], [agent_department], count(*) as [row_count]
    from @mockup
    where [agent_name] IS NOT NULL
    group by [agent_name],[agent_department]
)
SELECT agent_name,agent_department,row_count FROM cte
UNION ALL SELECT NULL,NULL,0 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte)=0;
```

The result

```
agent_name  agent_department    row_count
NULL        NULL                0
```

You see, that the resultset is called *as is*, while there is a `UNION ALL SELECT` query, which will deliver only in cases, where the cte has no rows.

Now we insert some data to the table

```
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES('blah','blub');
WITH cte AS
(
    select [agent_name], [agent_department], count(*) as [row_count]
    from @mockup
    where [agent_name] IS NOT NULL
    group by [agent_name],[agent_department]
)
SELECT agent_name,agent_department,row_count FROM cte
UNION ALL SELECT NULL,NULL,0 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte)=0;
```

the new result is now

```
agent_name  agent_department    row_count
blah        blub                1
```